# BOOTSTRAP how to make a hamburger tag and hide it right away in home page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry i'm very new to bootstrap. I have been successful making a hamburger tag, but I don't know how to hide it. I looked through a lot videos, but i can't figure out how to compress it together right at the home page.

Example like this,

https://colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/me-personal-resume-theme.jpg

Thank you so much !!

Comment: Can you be more specific about you want? That image just shows a hamburger button and you said you already created it. How do you want to hide it? There are a lot of ways to do that. For example, add `style="display:none;"` What have you done so far?

Comment: You can find documentation on how to hide it here:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317679/how-to-add-hamburger-menu-in-bootstrap