# Hamburger icon menu doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put a hamburger button using bootstrap classes but it just doens't work, the button doesn't appear anywhere.

Actually, any of the Glyphicons are working for me. Did I do something wrong? Am I forgeting of import something or what?

I hope anyone could please give me a hand with this problem.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>       
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="projeto.css">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>    
<body>    
<section>    
<div id="pai" class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-xl-10">
        <nav>
            <nav class="navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">                       
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>                       
                 </div>
            </nav>
       </nav>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Take a look at this :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317679/how-to-add-hamburger-menu-in-bootstrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 - Glyphicons migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `bootstrap v4`, the class `icon-bar` no more exist. so in `V4` you need to write like as follows or switch to `bootstrap v3`. 
[Ref link](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/)

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: And how do I change the bars color?

Comment: its svg image you can overwrite at `..navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon{background-image:url('your image link')}`