# Navbar not turning into a burger or being responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I've tried customizing my navbar, I've copied the basic navbar from the bootstrap site for 3.0. Now, my nav does not change into a burger nav, the custom background image i'm using for the nav sticks, the logo sticks, but the nav buttons disappear. I'm presuming they turn into a burger below the background image or off screen.

```css
.navbar {
  background: url(../images/mainnav.png) no-repeat top center;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.navspace {
  padding: 30px 46px 30px 46px;
}

.navposition {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container nopadding">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria- expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>max-width: 100%
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -
    ->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-
    collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navposition">
            <li class="navspace"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="navspace"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li class="navspace"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
            <li class="navspace"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 banner ">
            <p>10% off all pizzas
                <br>this weekend only</p>
            <h1>LIMITED TIME<br>ONLY</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row thumbnails">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3">
            <img src="images/bodyimg.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317679/how-to-add-hamburger-menu-in-bootstrap) it might help

Comment: what is that? `</button>max-width: 100%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems with your HTML. Some elements are commented out, surplus of closing tags like `</li>` or `</ul>`, also you have `max-width:100%` in your html. That has no business being there.

Regarding your question, the problem is that you set `.navbar { width:980px }` so ofcourse that when you are on a screen smaller than `980px`  not all the `.navbar` will be visible ( the right side of the navbar doesn't fit inside the screen ) so the burger menu is there but is not visible because the `navbar` is larger than the screen

If you want your .navbar to be of 980px but also responsive ( scale when screen smaller ) , use `max-width:980px`

see below

```css
.navbar {
  background: url(../images/mainnav.png) no-repeat top center;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.navspace {
  padding: 30px 46px 30px 46px;
}

.navposition {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container nopadding">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria- expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -
->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-
collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navposition">
        <li class="navspace"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navspace"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li class="navspace"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
        <li class="navspace"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 banner ">
      <p>10% off all pizzas
        <br>this weekend only</p>
      <h1>LIMITED TIME<br>ONLY</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row thumbnails">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3">
      <img src="images/bodyimg.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the burger appears now, small question do you happen to know how to have my custom background image change to a solid color background it's smaller?

Comment: you can use media queries for that. for example `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar { background-image:none;background-color:red;}

}`

Comment: Accepted! I've added that to my CSS but nothing has changed.

Comment: @LukeSciberras well. at what screen size do you want your background to change from image to color ?

Answer (score -2):

I've had the same problem. The solution for me was setting the background-color for the icon bars in css:

```
.icon-bar {
    background-color: black;
}
```