# Hamburger menu button shows me checkbox

Tags: css, hamburger-menu

I am studying the example given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317679/how-to-add-hamburger-menu-in-bootstrap#26320007). But I couldn't be able to see `hamburger` button. I see only the `checkbox` which is functioning like `hamburger` button as I expected.

**Questions:**

1. How to replace checkbox by hamburger button?
2. I had tried `hidden-md` `hidden-lg` and also `visible-xs`. But hamburger button does not hide. Where am I wrong?

**My Repository:**
In `module3`
https://github.com/elcolie/ychaikin-assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This icon from your exemple is an icon from Bootstrap, but it's Bootstrap 3, now if you are using Bootstrap 4 there is no this feature.
Use FontAwesome https://fontawesome.com/ if you want use it.

Comment: I am trying Bootstrap4. Please wait for a moment. This is my early period of `frontend` skill

Comment: Got the 2nd answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4#45683167