# drop down hamburger not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am just not sure what i am missing on this drop down hamburger iam pretty sure my data-target is right

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNav">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
          <div class="navbar-brand">T<span> - </span>C<!--<img src="#">--></div>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myNav">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#employment">Employment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#connect">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </nav>
```

Comment: Where is your script?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317679/how-to-add-hamburger-menu-in-bootstrap

And this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar

Answer (score 0):

You need an `onclick` event on your button. There's currently nothing telling it what to do when you click the button. To get you started, you'll need to modify you `button` tag to something like:

`<button onclick="toggleMenu" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNav">`

Then, add some script:

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  menu.classList.toggle('open-menu'); //toggle is an awesome built in function that does just what you want. It will add this class if it doesn't exists, and remove it if it does
}
```

After that, you'll have to add some CSS to style your menu for when it's opened.

Comment: You can see I've removed the `type="button"` attribute you had. Not necessary when using button tag.

Comment: This is build in in Bootstrap, no need to add scripts for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, just be sure that your view width is less than 768px, otherwise the hamburger will be hidden.