# Burger menu doesn't close (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css

I have this navigation bar that I did with bootstrap. When the burger appears, and you click on it, open the menu, but when you click again, doesn't close anymore. I'm searching what will be the problem, but I didn't find what's the problem.

the classes: "dark-blue" and "inter-sb" are classes only for font-family and color.

```
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar-burger" aria-controls="navbar-burger" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mt-4" id="navbar-burger">
            
            <ul class="navbar-nav inter-sb mx-auto">

                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="dark-blue nav-link me-5"><ins>PROJET</ins></ins></a></li>

                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="dark-blue nav-link me-5 ms-5"><ins>À PROXIMITÉ</ins></a></li>

                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="dark-blue nav-link me-5 ms-5"><ins>PHASES</ins></a></li>

                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="dark-blue nav-link me-5 ms-5"><ins>MODE DE VIE</ins></a></li>

                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="dark-blue nav-link ms-5"><ins>TERRAINS</ins></a></li>


            </ul>

        </div>

    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked very often here on stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bootstrap+hamburger). For example could your question be answered here: [How to add hamburger menu in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317679/how-to-add-hamburger-menu-in-bootstrap)